When does Episode 5 of Dogs of Berlin actually take place within the story?
There seems to be a bug, if not a typo, in Dogs of Berlin. Episode 2 (Mannschaft) clearly states that it happens on 'Mittwoch' (Wednesday, '6 Tage vorher'), while Episode 5 (Schiebung) states that it occurs on 'Freitag' (Friday, '3 Tage vorher'). If Episode 5 really takes place on Friday, it should be '4 Tage vorher'; otherwise, Episode 5 would actually be on Saturday instead of Friday.
So, when does Episode 5 of Dogs of Berlin actually take place within the story?
